# which data structure to use for phrase match

Tags: data-structures, nlp

Given a phrase I want to check if one of the entries in a predefined list of phrases is contained in the phrase ("phrase match"). The predefined list of phrases may be huge, and I'm reading it from a file. 
If I was looking for an exact match, I would have read the list into a hush. But since I'm not looking for an exact match, I don't know which data structure to use. 
Do I have to go over the entire list for each new phrase? Do you know of a data structure that fits a phrase match purpose?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: You might want to search online to see how the unix command `grep` works.

Comment: It would help to explain what do you mean by saying you're not looking for an exact match. How do you define phrase similarity in your program?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636371/efficient-data-structure-for-substring-search

Comment: How huge will be the list of phrases and how frequently will you search a word in it?